# Importing Compass styles with Sass using Yeoman

Tags: compass-sass, yeoman

I created a project using `yo webapp` (with the `generator-webapp` installed obviously).
Everything is fine, but I'm still missing something. I'm sure it's such an easy answer that I'll never come back to SO because I'll be too embarrassed.

I want to use Compass, which comes out of the box with Yeoman, but I don't know how. I mean, obviously `@import "compass...etc"` inside any Sass files won't work since inside `app/bower_components` (the default path for Sass `@import`s specified inside `Gruntfile.js`) there's no `compass` directory.

What should I do now in order to import Compass stylesheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use compass just as you would usually do. If you set up a vanilla compass project with `compass create`, there is `compass` folder either. If you want to use any of the helpers compass ships with, you can import them just as described in the documentation, e.g.

```
@import "compass/css3";

.mybox {
    @include box-shadow(red 2px 2px 10px);
}
```

*main.scss*

Answer (score 1):

You would have to install grunt task for compass with `npm install grunt-contrib-compass` and adjust your `Gruntfile.js` to add a task for compass compilation.

It may appear not that easy since it has some tricky parts like to compile your sass to `.temp/main.css` to use for testing/livereload, and then minify it into your `dist` when doing final build.

The most easy way might be to just try another generator that has compass in a separate directory. For example `angular` generator has compass and even bootstrap for compass. It's pretty cool.